# Reading from files

Tags: c, file

Yesterday in my class we started working with files for the first time. I wanted to see how it works, so I made a program where I write a word and that word has to be written in a certain file(that part worked). After that, I wanted to read from that file a number of characters and show it on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int df,m;
    char c[50],d[50];
    printf("c= \n");
    gets(c);
    m=strlen(c);
    df=open("e:\\codeblocks\\fisperimente\\text2.txt",O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY);
    if (df==-1) {printf("error");exit(1);}
    write(df,c,m);
    /*int i,n;
    n=read(df,d,5);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",d[i]);
    } */

    close(df);
    return 0;
}
```

What I put in my commentary is the part that doesn`t work. I noticed that if I printf n, it returns -1, which means that I did something wrong while reading from the file.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would avoid `gets()` at all costs.  It is unsafe, and is considered *deprecated*.  It may be removed in the future.  Instead, consider using `fgets()`, like so:

```
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
```

Next, your `open` is suspicious:

```
df=open("e:\\codeblocks\\fisperimente\\text2.txt",O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY);
```

Read only and write only are mutually exclusive.  If you want to open a file for both read and write, you need `O_RDWR`.

And finally, after you write to your file, the file pointer points to the end of file.  If you want to reread it, you need to seek back to the beginning.  This will do that:

```
lseek(df, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Once you do that, you can read your file back in.

Comment: Hey, what does the 3rd parameter of lseek mean?

Comment: The second parameter is an offset.  The third parameter says what that offset is relative to. `SEEK_SET` means "relative to the start of the file." `SEEK_CUR` means "relative to the current position." `SEEK_END` means "relative to the end of the file."

Comment: @user3078259 : If one of these answers did answer your question, be sure to mark that answer as "accepted."  It will then remove your question from the "unanswered" list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to seek to the beginning of the file, to read it's contents back. Or you can just close it or open it again for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try use flag `O_RDWR`, the or'd result of read only and write only flags is not what you think it does ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that mode `O_RDWR` is not usually equal to `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY`.  Therefore, you probably opened the file with `O_WRONLY` (classically, `O_RDONLY` is `0`).  This is not yet your major problem; it will become one.

Comment: I used O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY because that is how our professor told us we could read and write from a file. I used Michael's advice, I reopened it and it worked (I used only RD_ONLY when I opened it the second time), and then I realised that my RDONLY from the first open was useless. Thank you all, problem resolved.

Comment: Please discuss this with your prof — he needs to correct his notes, at minimum.